# Bash script using jq: --arg value not utilized with script

Tags: bash, jq

I have a bash script where a parameter is passed in which I am trying to use in a subsequent jq query, but I cannot get it to work. The command works when using manual inputs in cli, but not when passing the parameter to a script. Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
ACCOUNT=123456789
ENTITY=$1
DASHBOARDS=$(aws quicksight list-dashboards --aws-account-id ${ACCOUNT} | jq -r --arg e "$ENTITY" '.DashboardSummaryList[] | select(.Name|contains("$e")) | .DashboardId')
```

Another problem I ran into is that select contains is case sensitive. To solve it I first made sure the parameter is translated into full lowercase to be caught in a if statement. This statement handles full uppercase exceptions (such as "UK"), or returns a default value of first character being uppercase and the rest lowercase

```
ENTITY=$(echo "$1" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')  #Set parameter all lowercase

if [ "$ENTITY" = "uk" ] || [ "$ENTITY" = "exception2" ]; then
  ENTITY=$(echo ${ENTITY^^}) #All uppercase
else
  ENTITY=$(echo ${ENTITY^}) #First char uppercase
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if `.Name` contains the literal string `$e`; the variable does not need to be quoted.

```
... select(.Name|contains($e)) | ...
```